# Continuity of the indefinite integral $|f|^p$ on $L^p$,where $0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In our functional analysis class, we use the book of Walter Rudin.
In our discussion, this topic came up and I have a question in mind: 
Let $0<p<1$ and consider the $L^p$ space whose elements are those Lebesgue measurable functions $f$ for which $\Delta(f)=\int_0^1 |f(t)|^p<\infty$ with the usual identification of functions that coincide almost everywhere. We have shown that $L^p$ is a locally bounded $F$-space. We claim that $L^p$ contains no convex open sets, other than $\emptyset$ and $L^p$. Throughout its proof, the book mentioned of the following: 
By the continuity of the indefinite integral of $|f|^p$, there are points $0=x_o<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1$ such that 
$\displaystyle \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} |f(t)|^p dt=n^{-1}\Delta(f)~~~~~~~~~~~(1\leq i\leq 1$).

> > Question: How are we going to choose these points $x_i$ using the continuity of the continuity of the indefinite integral of $|f|^p$?

Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $F(t) = \int_0^x |f(t)|^p\,dt$. This is a continuous increasing function on $[0,1]$. By the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), for every $i=1,\dots,n-1$ there exists $x_i\in (0,1)$ such that 
$$F(x_i)=\frac{i}{n} F(1)$$
These are the points you choose. Indeed, 
$$\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} |f(t)|^p\,dt = F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1}) = \frac{i}{n} F(1)-\frac{i-1}{n} F(1) = \frac{1}{n}\Delta(f)$$